# Access to file in /root folder

Tags: 16.04, permissions, root

I am a new Linux user. I am trying to open a file called `vtkOBJReader.cxx` which is giving me this error:

```
ERROR: In /root/VTK-7.1.1/IO/Geometry/vtkOBJReader.cxx, line 271
```

So basically I want to get access to `/root/VTK-7.1.1/IO/Geometry` and open that file in order to understand why it is giving me the error. I tried to use `gksu nautilus` to access /root, but it's giving me this:

[image]

There's only a `Desktop` folder and nothing else. How can I get access to `/root/VTK-7.1.1/IO/Geometry`?

EDIT: If I type `sudo ls -al /root/VTK-7.1.1/IO/Geometry/` I get `ls: cannot access '/root/VTK-7.1.1/IO/Geometry/': No such file or directory:`

Comment: Please run `sudo sed -n '260,+30p'  filename`, this will print line 260 and the following 30 lines to your terminal. Please copy this and paste it into your question, then modify your question to make more sense (what are you actually trying to achieve).

Comment: @pzkpfw from where (i.e. inside which folder) should I run that command? Because if I do it from home directory I get `can't read vtkOBJReader.cxx: No such file or directory`, also giving the absolute path it's not working.

Comment: Which command do you use to find the file?

Comment: @ADDB I am not good at all with Linux, so I was just trying to reach `/root/VTK-7.1.1/IO/Geometry` and then look for the file by myself. I was not using any "find" command

Comment: Using the absolute path should work, i.e. `sudo sed -n '260,+30p' /root/VTK-7.1.1/IO/Geometry/vtkOBJReader.cxx` -- since you're running the command as root (sudo) if the file exists it should show you the line.

Comment: So basically you have a program/command that tries to open that file but can't. If you're trying @pzkpfw it shows that this file doesn't exist. Did you think about the possibility that this file, out of whatever reason, doesn't exist?

Comment: Giving the absolute path is not working, I still get `sed: can't read /root/VTK-7.1.1/IO/Geometry/vtkOBJReader.cxx: No such file or directory`

Comment: @ADDB Yes I have a programm that is calling the .cxx file, but this file is raising an error: `ERROR: In /root/VTK-7.1.1/IO/Geometry/vtkOBJReader.cxx, line 271
vtkOBJReader (0x2243970): Error reading 'v' at line 3`. Basically it is failing at reading another file that my program is giving it as input. All I want to do is open the .cxx file, and understand why it's failing at reading the input file I am giving it.

Comment: Can you please add the output of `sudo ls -al /root/VTK-7.1.1/IO/Geometry/` to your question so that we can see the directory contents. Also, is there a good reason why you're running VTK 7.1.1 as root, and why it's installed in /root? This all seems very non-standard

Comment: Open Terminal with `ctrl + a + t` and type `sudo ls -a /root` if you find your VTK directory, use `sudo cd /root/VTK-7.1.1/IO/Geometry` and then type again `sudo ls -a` if your file is not listed now, it does not exist. You can use the `tab` to autocomplete.

Comment: no VTK directory inside /root. Does that mean VTK does not exist? How can it raise that error then?

Comment: @pzkpfw I have no idea on why VTK is installed in /root. It has been installed as part of a repository I got from github. But at this point I don't understand if it's really there or not.

Comment: Is there a `VTK-7.1.1` in your `~` (that is, your home directory)? If so, it's possible some sloppy coding somewhere is replacing your home directory with `/root` because you're running the update process as root. How to fix? No idea. I would remove the application, the repo, and make a clean install in another way (another repo, official if possible, or try and  compile from source, which normally isn't as hard as it sounds).